# python quicksort using rescursion

Tags: python, algorithm, quicksort

I know it could be duplicated, but haven't figured out which part of my code causes recursion error.
It should use less than 1000 stacks which is the recursion limit in Python.

```
import random

def quick_sort(arr):
    # if array is empty or has only 1 element
    # it means the array is already sorted, so return it.
    if len(arr) < 2:
        return arr
    else:
        rand_index = random.randint(0,len(arr)-1)
        pivot = arr[rand_index]
        less = []
        greater = []

        # create less and greater array comparing with pivot
        for i in arr:
            if i <= pivot:
                less.append(i)
            else:
                greater.append(i)

        return quick_sort(less) + [pivot] + quick_sort(greater)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sample_array = [6,3,7,2,7,4,7,3,21,54,0,6,5,3,1,3]
    sorted_array = quick_sort(sample_array)
    print(sorted_array)
```

The error code is here below:

```
  File "quick_sort.py", line 24, in <module>
    sorted_array = quick_sort(sample_array)
  File "quick_sort.py", line 20, in quick_sort
    return quick_sort(less) + [pivot] + quick_sort(greater)
  File "quick_sort.py", line 20, in quick_sort
    return quick_sort(less) + [pivot] + quick_sort(greater)
  File "quick_sort.py", line 20, in quick_sort
    return quick_sort(less) + [pivot] + quick_sort(greater)
  [Previous line repeated 991 more times]
  File "quick_sort.py", line 9, in quick_sort
    rand_index = random.randint(0,len(arr)-1)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\random.py", line 221, in randint
    return self.randrange(a, b+1)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\random.py", line 197, in randrange
    return istart + self._randbelow(width)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\random.py", line 231, in _randbelow
    if type(random) is BuiltinMethod or type(getrandbits) is Method:
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Your help would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `i <= pivot` This condition!! When you iterate over arr, you include `pivot` as well. So your end result array will have more elements than the original array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to add equal numbers to `less`. Add it to new array and put it in middle of your return statement. Try this:

```
def quick_sort(arr):
    # if array is empty or has only 1 element
    # it means the array is already sorted, so return it.
    if len(arr) < 2:
        return arr
    else:
        rand_index = random.randint(0,len(arr)-1)
        pivot = arr[rand_index]
        less = []
        equal_nums = []
        greater = []

        # create less and greater array comparing with pivot
        for i in arr:
            if i < pivot:
                less.append(i)
            if i > pivot:
                greater.append(i)
            if i == pivot:
                equal_nums.append(i)

        return quick_sort(less) + equal_nums + quick_sort(greater)
```

Or try to use(and understand) more pythonic solution:

```
def qsort(L):
    if L: return qsort([x for x in L if x<L[0]]) + [x for x in L if x==L[0]] + qsort([x for x in L if x>L[0]])
    return []
```

Comment: Is it ok to always set the pivot value as L[0]? Does that cause lower performance when sorting? I am just curious. Your answer is very helpful though thanks!

Comment: @TreyYi it depends on input data. If your input data will be sorted array with reverse order - this is bad.

Comment: @TreyYi i made an edit to my answer: replace `else` with `if i == pivot`. Now it works correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did use `if i < pivot, elif i > pivot, else` # else for equal check.

Answer (score 0):

You should temporarily remove pivot element from list or exchange it with the last element and make loop excluding the last element. Otherwise it takes part in sorting again and again, causing too deep recursion and stackoverflow

Corrected working code:

```
def quick_sort(arr):
    # if array is empty or has only 1 element
    # it means the array is already sorted, so return it.
    if len(arr) < 2:
        return arr
    else:
        rand_index = random.randint(0,len(arr)-1)
        pivot = arr[rand_index]
        less = []
        greater = []

        arr[-1], arr[rand_index] = arr[rand_index], arr[-1]


        # create less and greater array comparing with pivot
        for i in range(len(arr)-1):
            if arr[i] <= pivot:
                less.append(arr[i])
            else:
                greater.append(arr[i])

        return quick_sort(less) + [pivot] + quick_sort(greater)

>>> [0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 21, 54]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your are always adding `pivot` to `less` when populating the list.

When the algorithm hits the point where it needs to sort the list `[3, 3, 3, 3]`, it picks an arbitrary pivot, create a new list `less` which will again contain all the values (because all the 3's are less than equal to the pivot 3). When it tries to sort this new list which is identical to the original one, it eventually leads to an infinite recursion.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
rand_index = random.randint(0,len(arr)-1)
pivot = arr[rand_index]
less = []
equal = []
greater = []

# create less and greater array comparing with pivot
for i in arr:
    if i < pivot:
        less.append(i)
    elif i == pivot:
        equal.append(i)
    else:
        greater.append(i)

return quick_sort(less) + equal + quick_sort(greater)
```

Comment: This will skip values which are equal to `pivot` from sorting.

Comment: using `elif` and `else` you can avoid two unnecessary conditional checkings